# GZIP compression did not work good for a data of 64K

Tags: java, compression

Hi I have created compressin and decompression technique using gZipinputstream in both c#.NET and java
If I compress upto 15000 bytes in c#.NET then i can decompress it in java
but if i compress 64000 bytes in c#.NET then i am not able to decompress it in java.
But I can decompress it using C#.NET.
So how to come out of this problem

Thanks
Bapi

Comment: You need to show us some code. This is almost certainly something wrong with the way you're doing it.

Comment: Try also to explain what /does/ happen instead of what /doesn't/ happen. You try to ungzip 64k of gzipped data in Java and it doesn't work. But what does happen? Investigating this alone might lead you down the right path, and it may well highlight to others the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess you are probably using DEFLATE_64 in the .net code. This will compress in up to 64K blocks, DEFLATE, which is what Java supports only compresses up to 32K blocks. On the .net side, try setting your compressor to only use DEFLATE instead of allowing it to use DEFLATE_64 and you might have more luck.

Comment: We are using GZipInputStream in both java and c#.NET, we are not using Deflate